# Changing value of input element without changing element id

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an ASPX page with an input element.  On page load I set the value of that input element.  Later on I try to get the contents of that field using the elements id(using javascript) but it fails because the id has been changed.  Is there any way to stop C# from changing the elements id?

input element:

```
<input id="conferenceDate" runat="server" style="width:100%;" />
```

Setting the date in the `Page_Load` function:

```
conferenceDate.Value = DateTime.Now.ToString();
```

The id after the element vale has been set:

```
<input name="ctl00$PlaceHolderMain$conferenceDate" type="text" id="ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_conferenceDate"     style="width:100%;" value="7/21/2014 11:30:55 AM" />
```

---

**UPDATE:** I have tried the following but neither work the id is still changed:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="conferenceDate" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" />
```

and

When I try to select them later with jQuery I have to use the altered id:

```
$("ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_conferenceDate").val()
```

Comment: Is your control in a content page that uses a master page?

Comment: Yes it uses a master page

Comment: Have you tried using `ClientId`?

Comment: How could that hlep me get the id with javascript later?

Comment: your javascript is processed through your server.  The server recognizes the tag and replaces it with the proper ID that its generated.  So you have the altered id's, but you're able to easily reference them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In addition to setting the `ClientIDMode` to `static`, you can also find the `id` using the [`ClientID`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientid(v=vs.110).aspx) property.

```
<%= conferenceDate.ClientID %>
```

Using your sample information you can find it like this:

Single or double quotes and dont forget the hash mark (or dot if its a class).

```
$("#<%= conferenceDate.ClientID %>").val()
```

Comment: @Timigen, that is not true, the quotes are needed.  Depending on your code however it might require single quotes instead of double.

Comment: @Timigen .Net version shouldnt matter.  But hey, if it works, it works. :)

Comment: $("<%= conferenceDate.ClientID %>").val() and $('<%= conferenceDate.ClientID %>').val() result in undefined.  If you use $(<%= conferenceDate.ClientID %>).val() I get the intended result.

Comment: @Timigen, i'm sure that if you look at the output, you'll see that the first two are not being converted to the proper names.  Why this is will depend on the larger structure of your page.

Comment: conferenceDate is an html input field.  I am simply letting people know what worked for me and what did not.  In case they find them selves in the same position...

Comment: @Timigen, I'm with you on that.  When i say output, I mean that you should view the source of the page after its been processed by IIS.  This will give you insight into exactly why its happening.

Comment: well if i console.log("<%= conferenceStartDate.ClientID %>") it logs  "ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_conferenceStartDate".  So maybe its the missing hash mark that causes $("<%= conferenceStartDate.ClientID %>").val() to come back undefined?

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the ClientIDMode of the Textbox to "Static" (More info: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientidmode(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
<input id="conferenceDate" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" style="width:100%;" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the [ClientIDMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientidmode(v=vs.110).aspx) to `Static`.

This will prevent the controls `ID` from changing at runtime.

E.g:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="conferenceDate" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not to use the asp:textbox and set the ClientIDMode to static?

```
<asp:TextBox ID="conferenceDate" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static"></asp:TextBox>
```